# Drawn content lost on window overlap in GTK#

Tags: c#, gtk#, cairo

I am using Cairo in a GTK# application for drawing. When another window covers part of the drawn content, the overlapped part of the drawn content is lost. Is there a way to make it permanent?

Here is my simplified method for drawing the content:

```
void UpdateConnectionLines ()
{
    GdkWindow myWindow = GetGdkWindow();
    myWindow.Clear ();
    using (Context g = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (myWindow))
    {
        g.Save ();
        g.MoveTo (0, 20);
        g.LineTo (100, 20);
        g.Restore ();
        g.Color = new Color (0, 0, 0);
        g.LineWidth = 1;
        g.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Evaluating John Koerner's answer, I have found a solution, that works for every GTK# widget. I use the <strike>generic `WidgetEvent`</strike> `ExposeEvent` (thanks, ptomato) and redraw.

I append my event handler with

```
this.ExposeEvent += new global::Gtk.ExposeEventHandler (this.Handle_ExposeEvent);
```

and then the handler just calls my method:

```
protected virtual void Handle_ExposeEvent (object o, Gtk.ExposeEventArgs args)
{
    UpdateConnectionLines();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, I have not RTF[M](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo) correctly, as it explicitely states:

> The best place to create and use the
>   Context is the ExposeEvent for the
>   given widget. Usually you'll want to
>   use the Gtk.DrawingArea for this task.
>   An example implementation of the
>   Expose event method:

Comment: What? You repaint every time there's any event? Why don't you paint in the paint handler?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the paint handler for GTK#? I cannot find the handler in the documentation.

Comment: It should be `WidgetExposeEvent`, at least for GTK 2. The `WidgetEvent` will fire any time there's any event, including the expose event, so this works, but it's really wasteful.

Comment: If you basically followed John's suggestion, then why didn't you accept **his** answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you are drawing directly on the form, then you need to do it in the Form's paint event, to ensure it is there every time the form get's painted (i.e. when another window covers it and then moves, when it is resized, ...)

Comment: I cannot find the Paint event in the GTK# documentation, nor do I get a hint for the Gtk.Window or Gtk.Widget class in Monodevelop.

Comment: The paint event is the signal `expose-event` in GTK 2 or `draw` in GTK 3.